# How to create new fragments when adding and removing fragments using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to do something pretty basic but can't seem to get it to work.

I have a `ViewPager` and am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to populate it with fragments. I always  have 3 fragments (call them A, B, C) and on fragment C I have a simple `ListView`. Whenever the user clicks an item on that ListView, I want to add a new fragment (Fragment D) to the ViewPager which will show details related to that list item.

If the user goes back to Fragment C, they can click on another list item and the contents of Fragment D should be updated with other details.

This is the code for the PageAdapter:

```
public class TopPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public TopPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        fragments.add(0, new FragmentA());
        fragments.add(1, new FragmentB());
        fragments.add(2, new FragmentC());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public void addFragmentD(FragmentD frag) {
        fragments.add(3, frag);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragmentD() {
        fragments.remove(3);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used (when the user clicks on a list item in Fragment C):

```
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FragmentD frag = new FragmentD();

                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("name", mName.getText().toString());
                        frag.setArguments(args);

                        adapter.addFragmentD(frag);
                    }
});
```

And this is the actual code of Fragment D (all it does is get the bundle that is passed to it and display it):

```
public class FragmentD extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private TextView mName;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.mContext = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d, container, false);

        mName=  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        String name = (String) getArguments().get("name");
        mName.setText(name);

        return view;
    }

}
```

The end result is that FragmentD gets added correctly and it displays the correct info that gets passed to it via the Bundle, but it only works the first time. If I go back to FragmentC and click on another list item, that same FragmentD shows up and even though I am creating a new instance of FragmentD, its `onCreateView` method never get called. It's as if it stays in memory and never removed.

Any ideas how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: where do you call the removeFragmentD()? Have you tried to replace the fragment on click instead of adding it? Moreover, do you really need to recreate a whole fragment instead of simply changing its content?

Comment: There's actually a 'close' button on Fragment D that calls removeFragmentD() and takes the user back to Fragment C (I removed it from here to make the code simpler). I actually don't need to recreate the fragment, I could just update its content.